# Can I send bitcoins with my mobile phone?

Tags: transactions, client, mobile, android, ios

Is it possible to send and receive bitcoins with a mobile phone? If so, are there bitcoin clients for Android or iOS?

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4214/516

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use Bitcoin by Bitcoin Android. It is unmaintained, it starts crashing and doesn't load anymore, and there is no way to get your bitcoins out. Someone should really get the developer to take it down. I'm emailing him again now.

Use [Bitcoin Wallet](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet&hl=en). It is maintained by the same team that creates the bitcoinj android library. It is the most reliable app.

Use the [MtGox mobile app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mtgoxlive.trader). This is the best way to ensure that you do not lose coins if the app crashes, since your coins are held at mtgox.

[Blockchain](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=piuk.blockchain) has a mobile wallet now as well. Looks very promising.

Comment: If you have an Android Bitcoin wallet app that ceases to work leaving you with lost coins, this article may help: http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2011/12/28/how-to-recover-lost-bitcoins-from-an-android-wallet/

Comment: The link to [Blockchain](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=piuk.blockchain) seems to be broken.

Answer (score 8):

There are at least two actual clients for Android and half a dozen "thin clients" that connect to a bitcoin server at home. As the thin clients are kind of complicated installs, I recommend [Bitcoin Wallet](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet&hl=en) by [Andreas Schildbach](https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Andreas%20Schildbach). 
There are a few questions of security as both apps have no way (that I'm aware of) to import/export/backup wallets and it's uncertain what level of security is held on data Google keeps in the cloud, but for carrying a small amount of coin for daily use, both are viable options.

Not being an iOS person I can't weigh in on the features etc. of the various iOS apps, but a quick glance over the various projects seems to show an assortment of thin clients and no actual iOS-based bitcoind implementation.

Comment: I have successfully used the bitcoin wallet app mentioned. I'd recommend it too.

Comment: can we get rid of this answer if it includes a recommendation for a buggy and unmaintained wallet app?

Comment: I can edit this answer per a valid recommendation. Which app listed is buggy and unmaintained?

Comment: See the comment and answer by Osmosis (Bitcoin Android). Really though, would be nice to have a couple other people weigh in here on current features/vulnerabilities of mobile clients. Also, iOS?

Comment: I can certainly vouch for Andreas Schildbach's Bitcoin Wallet - first rate.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an e-wallet or an exchange to send bitcoins. Most websites can be accessed with a phone so you don't have to install anything.

MtGox already has a [mobile application](http://mtgoxlive.com/mobile/) that you can use to access your account. I am sure other applications and mobile sites will appear soon.

Answer (score 1):

I want add that you can send Bitcoins from any mobile device via an SMS interface provided by [PHONECO.IN](http://phoneco.in/). At the moment, that service only has a US phone number, so it would be relatively expensive to use from Europe.

Disclaimer: I am in no way associated with that service and I do not know anything about security, nor quality of that service.

Answer (score 1):

BitPay for Android
Funds received are stored on InstaWallet, so you can spend them from any web browser as well.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bitcoin.bitpay&hl=en
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BitPay

Though know that your funds stored on instawallet requires no password -- only the privacy of the URL is what keeps someone from spending your coins.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BitcoinSpinner](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.miracleas.bitcoin_spinner) on Android phones. BitcoinSpinner is a light weight secure Bitcoin client, which is ready for use immediately after installation.

[BitcoinSpinner announcement at bitcointalk.org](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=52674.0)

Answer (score 1):

One more option to add to the list: You can use the blockchain.info [My Wallet](https://blockchain.info/wallet/).

- [Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=piuk.blockchain)
- [iPhone App](https://blockchain.info/wallet/iphone-app)
- Or login through the web interface in your phones browser.

We also offer [Instant SMS Deposits](https://blockchain.info/wallet/sms-phone-deposits)

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like [Qcan](https://qcan.com), they have a web app to send and receive bitcoin with your mobile number. I believe they have an Android app too.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 the most robust Crypto Wallet app for iOS and Android is [Exodus](https://www.exodus.com/download/).

Although the size of fees in Exodus wallet are rather high.