# What's the best Android wallet client for bitcoin?

Tags: wallet, e-wallet, thin-clients, android

There are many bitcoin wallet clients on android market. What is the best considering security, interoperability and usability?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep your private keys secret (on your phone, that is), I'd recommend

[Bitcoin Wallet for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet)

The app also does not imply any trust in single servers, as it manages the block chain on-device.

Comment: so how much space does it take up when it has to download the bitcoin block chain data to get synchronized?

Comment: For future searchers: I installed the app, resynchronized and it didn't seem to take more than 200MB.  I think it's only downloading 6 weeks worth of transactions.

Comment: I've been using this wallet and it came as an unpleasant surprise that it can not export the keys in the now de-facto standard [BIP39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) format (sequence of English words). I wanted to move my funds to another wallet without paying $5 as a tx fee. I had to export an encrypted database from the app in its own format and use command line tools to extract the raw private key (see [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3247/31712)). I'm not sure I can suggest an alternative though: I stopped storing coins on a phone altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I consider the [Blockchain.info Wallet](https://blockchain.info/wallet/) [Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=piuk.blockchain&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInBpdWsuYmxvY2tjaGFpbiJd) the best one on the market. It's no true client but an e-wallet but you can manage your own true wallets and addresses and your private keys are stored encrypted. The decryption happens on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

There are various factors that matter.

If you wish to use the same EWallet account from both the web as well as from the mobile, then mobile-only wallets would be excluded.

Also, since an EWallet service requires service from a back-end, availability can be a concern as well.

Here's a list of options:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mobile_Payment_Apps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [ImToken wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=im.token.app&hl=en_US) as you owe your own privatekey. And also they have integrated few markets inside it.The best part is it's very easy to use and completely decentralized.Always write down your mnemonic phrase in piece of paper and keep it is safe.

Recently they have raised 35 billion dollars for the development and 20 billion of coinbase customer asset is in ImToken.